# Rails 3: How can specify a layout to use for a specific method, but use the default application.html.erb otherwise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller with some methods and I want to use the default application.html.erb layout for all of them, except the #list method.  So I've declared the specific layout at the top of my controller for the #list method like so...

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
   layout "customlayout", :only => [:list]
```

but it appears that now I've lost the default application.html.erb layout for all the other methods in that controller.  What am I missing?

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a method to set the layout.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout :resolve_layout

private
  def resolve_layout
    case action_name
    when 'list'
      'customlayout'
    else
      'application'
    end
  end
end
```

You can also supply a proc to `layout` if you like.

Comment: Using a lambda, replace above with:                              layout lambda{ |c| (c.action_name == 'list') ? 'customlayout' : 'application' }